# How can I send an output to a PA from my combo practice amp?

Tags: amplifiers, amplification

This is long 
I play in a church choir . I have bough a combo practice amp (VOX PathFinder)to use as a monitor which is placed in front of me.

I assumed i would give the output from the combo amp to the PA. But since this is a practice amp , if the cable is plugged into the "headphones" socket, the amp does not produce a sound.

I've made a work around for this. My BOSS-ME70 has a monoand stereo outs. I have given mono to PA and stereo to the combo amp. So it works fine.

But this workaround is only for me. What if others want to connect just to the amp and play but need to connect to the PA too.

I just want to make it simple instead of all this fuss. The need is just plug and play. Connect only to one socket and play so that i get the sound both in the combo amp as well as the PA.

Please Help

Comment: You could mic the amp, if that's not too many "sockets" to connect...

Comment: Thank you but, That is physically not feasible. I would've gone for this if it had been so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your need is an amp with a *line out* socket. Plug guitar (presumably) into amp, line out goes to p.a. input channel. With your practice amp, the purpose of the headphone socket is to disconnect the speaker - for quiet practice!

If others want to share, with probably only one input, you're going to need a mixer first in line. Mixer> amp> p.a.

Another way is to plug guitar straight into p.a. input, then line out from *monitor out* on p.a. to your amp input. If other players want to share, that monitor out from p.a. can have their mixes fed to your amp through the p.a. All you seem to be doing is using a practice amp as a powered monitor then.

Maybe with judicious placing of p.a.speakers - or even you yourself, there won't be any need for this. If you could stand close to a p.a.speaker, that might be enough. And it's fewer leads to plug in and trip over!

Comment: This is a good idea. Will try connecting to the PA and take the monitor out into the amp's input. Thank you so much

Comment: Sending signal from a monitor out to a guitar practice amp does not seem like a good idea to me. You could very easily overload the amp with an abundance of frequencies it isn't designed to handle. Also, the gain on the monitor out is likely extremely higher than the typical gain from a guitar.

Comment: @h0r53 - 'overload the amp etc.?' It's only as a monitor, and overloading frequencies isn't that much of a problem. The speaker will give what it gives. Not ideal, maybe, but a solution nevertheless. Nothing and no-one gets hurt.

Answer (score 3):

If the sound from your amp is really what you want going through the PA, then the best way to get that exact sound is to mic the amp.  Part of the whole amp package is the speaker itself.  The only way to truly get that part of your amp into the mix is to mic the amp.

At the church that I play at, all of the electric guitar players use this method.  1) It recreates the exact sound that they like, 2) They are able to hear (from their own amp) exactly what is being sent to the mix.

This way you are able to use the amp that you already have and are comfortable with.  Plus most churches will have extra mics that can be used for your amp.

Comment: thank you for the advice. Firstly , it it physically not possible to arrange a mic where I stand. And no extra mics .I know about this practice of keeping a mic in front of the guitar speaker. The goal is also about other guitarists. They can directly plug into only the PA but and cannot use the combo. Because of this, they cannot hear themselves.

Comment: It is quite feasible to arrange a mic for the front of the amp. But it would probably need to be a radio mic. There are cheap ones about that would do the job - I bought a Sony at a car boot for less than £10 and it does the job fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need a di box with a pass-through.  Pass through TS to the amp and output XLR or TRS from the di box to the PA or mixer.  Place the di box before and not after the amp by plugging your guitar directly into its input.

Note that this is the preferred method when using a mixer but if using a PA you will get a much brighter signal from the guitar than you hear from the amplifier so if it's a lower-end PA that doesn't have any EQ capabilities for high-frequency roll off then you're better off miking your amp to get the exact same sound you hear on your stage monitor (amp).

Answer (score 0):

If your Amp has a speaker jack on the back, you can use that to connect an output style D.I. Box to the P.A. This is a D.I. box that is designed to handle the output level of an amp and reduce it back to line level for the P.A. These also have a parallel wired jack to send the speaker level signal to the speaker, so you have sound from your speaker and a feed to the P.A. with all the amplified characteristics. These are very often nothing more than a matching transformer, wired up and mounted in a box, but they work very well if they are designed correctly.

Comment: Hey , the combo does not have a speaker jack . But the DI idea sounds interesting. Can i have it this way guitar>DI , DI>combo/PA ?

Comment: @crimson_joey-There are D.I. Boxes designed for Before the Amp, and others that take the Amp output signal. You get to choose.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Boss Katana 100 head or a Black Star 100 head. Both have simulated speaker outputs. The Katana also has a line out. The latter has a higher output level than the simulated speaker out so we use that. We use in ears for monitoring.